# Django: convert this into DetailView - a view function using two parameters from a URL

Tags: django, django-views

I'm really happy to discover Class Based Views in Django. It fits my tiny brain better.

Now, I came across a situation where I directed users to a page based two parameters from the URL using a function view.

views.py

```
def step_detail(request, **kwargs):
    course_pk = kwargs["course_pk"]
    step_pk = kwargs["step_pk"]
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, course=course_pk, pk=step_pk)
    return render(request, "courses/step_detail.html", {"step": step})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("courses/<int:course_pk>/<int:step_pk>/", views.step_detail, name='step'),
]
```

The document says that you can only pass "pk" or "slug" into DetailView but here I have two parameters so I am out of luck.

By any chance is there still an elegant way to use Class Based Views here?

My repo is here: https://github.com/jeremy886/DjangoBasics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`query_pk_and_slug=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.query_pk_and_slug) attribute. Just set `course` field as slug using [`slug_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field):

```
class StepDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Step
    query_pk_and_slug=True
    slug_field = 'course'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'course_pk'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'step_pk'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override `get_object` to query based on anything you like.

```
def get_object(self, **kwargs):
    return Step.objects.get(course=course_pk, pk=step_pk)
```

Comment: This was a bit more advanced for me before. Now I see how it works. A more succinct solution.